# Is it good to store UI state directly within data model?

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, model-view-controller, state

This is a generic architecture question. So think MVC model where a model containing data is tied to certain UI fields, so they update simultaneously.

Now I need to store some UI state associated to that UI field, say a flag indicating whether the field is in edit mode. And the UI will update based on this edit flag, say it will show some edit controls when the edit flag is true.

So will I be better off reusing the data model and store the state within with other backend related data (I will certainly not send this flag back to the backend since backend concerns nothing about UI states), or create a new container to track the UI states?

Comment: Do you refer to server side as backend. I consider a persistent store as backend and server side programming (for eg. jsp/servlets etc in java) as frontend.

Comment: @pawindergupta yes I refer to the persistent store layer as the backend in this case, which handles fetching/updating the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the ui form /model becomes dirty (user first starts the first interaction with form), you would store the state of model(naturally the ui) in an object, let's call it 'bag'. 
You continuosly update the bag as user modifies the values. Before user tries to navigate away from the form (close window, go back and forth in browser etc), you can save this bag to cookie (if it is small) or do a post to your server and save it as a json object in a table with 4 fields like id, jsondata, modelUiIdentifier,userIdentifier. Later when that page is loaded later, you can get this data (if it exists for that model/ui and user) and hydrate your model object (which would update your ui automatically).

If you are using angularjs, just iterate through $scope object of the related ui section by copying its data (non "function" values in the $scope object and send to server like explained above)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, they are good points. However they don't really answer my question though, I was asking if I want to store UI states, is it worth adding a UI state flag (for example `editing = true`) into the model of that UI containing the data, or better to separate the UI states into another object?

Comment: You can do that. So, they will be in same place. You can attach an object like my model.editingstate={} and populate it with edit data which wouldn't pollute the model by being in a separate bag.

Comment: If I wanted to save ui state, I would save it separately and merge state data with model object b4 being displayed to user. I wouldn't want to my model with such extra fields. I hope that helps

Comment: What do you think about having a totally separate container for storing states? I.e. don't touch the model at all?

Comment: That is perfectly fine, it becomes LIKE object instantiation - you don't hardcode values to your objects, you instantiate them with relevant data. In similar fashion you are hydrating your model with relevant data (saved ui state). The more decoupled the better, you won't worry about states tripping on each other and will keep your sanity.

Answer (score 1):

State is data, data is state. With that in mind, if you need to store some UI state associated to UI field, use a factory to create an Object. Change that Object, you change the UI State. In addition, the factory can be reused across your project with a simple injection, manage state across different states, and its easy to test.

**Update:**

Simple demo of service managing data/state http://plnkr.co/edit/PdDmUz?p=preview

.html

```
<h3>Controller 1</h3>
  Check me, to check both: 
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected.data" />
  <pre>selected.data: {{selected.data}}</pre>


<h3>Controller 2</h3>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl2">
  Or, check me: 
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected2.data" />
  <pre>selected2.data: {{selected2.data}}</pre>
```

.js

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope,uiFieldState) {
    $scope.selected = uiFieldState.uiObject;
})

app.controller('MainCtrl2', function($scope,uiFieldState) {
    $scope.selected2 = uiFieldState.uiObject;
})

app.factory('uiFieldState', function () {
    return {uiObject: {data: null} };
});
```

Comment: In my mind I refer to "data" as the actual data stored in the database (like username) and the purpose of binding it to a UI is to display and potentially update it through the UI. However, state is a pure visual state (like if the field is in focus, or in edit mode), which I don't consider is worth going into the same model containing backend data. So in your answer, are you suggesting me to store the UI states in a different object?

Comment: Username 'data' typically is used to create a persistent authorization/permissions 'state' service, any 'edit mode' functions would be conditional applied in the 'state' based on the user permissions levels 'data'. Above I've added example of UI state using service Object. Here is an example app (from the app development with angularJS book) with a service using a Object to controlling things like 'edit modes' https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/blob/master/client/src/common/security/security.js#L99